# elasticsearch cannot read certificate file - linux file permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, elasticsearch, certbot

I generated a certificate file with certbot. It is placed in `/etc/letsencrypt/...`.

I created a group called `elk` where I added the `elasticsearch` user, and I recursively set it as the owning group for `/etc/letsencrypt` and recursively set the permissions to `770`.

When I start elasticsearch via `systemctl start elasticsearch.service`, it is not able to read the file? `Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem" "read")`

Why is that?

What strategy would you recommend to be able to use the same certificate for elasticsearch and kibana?

Comment: Have you added the certificate file to the group `elk`?

Comment: I used the `chgrp -R elk /etc/letsencrypt` command followed by `chmod -R 770 /etc/letsencrypt`. Are you referring to something else?

Comment: May you please check the group setting for file `/etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem` ?

Comment: Is the service also running with that group?

Comment: What's the output of `ps -o pid,user,group,supgrp,args -C java` and `namei -l /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem`

Comment: What OS/Linux distribution is it and are things like apparmor/selinux enabled?

Comment: In any case `chmod -R 770` doesn't make sense. You don't want to give execute permissions to non-directory files in there and you don't want to give write access to anyone.

Comment: @paladin `lrwxrwxrwx  1 root elk   44 Mar 19 16:18 fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/logs.aico.swiss/fullchain1.pem*`

@StéphaneChazelas I am using Ubuntu on AWS EC2. I think due to the `ps -o pid...` command I figured the user is called `elastic` not `elasticsearch`. The latter is the group... In regards to the permissions, I gave 777 due to frustration. I will restrict it once it works. Will try more tomorrow and update